# Change texture by script c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures

I'm having trouble switching texture to a mesh, when I'm getting near to the mesh the new texture should appear:

```
string name = picture.name;
Texture2D tex = (Texture2D)Resources.Load(name, typeof(Texture2D));
picture.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
```

What i want to do is revert the old texture when I'm getting far and I'm not able to do that in any way...
I believe that the problem is that

```
Texture old = picture.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.GetTexture ("_MainTex");
```

gets the name of the picture everytime even if it's changed, so the current texture name is saved and I can't get back the original one.

PS: my textures are dynamic, i can't set those in the inspector.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class pictures : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject[] pictures;
    public GameObject player;

    void Start() {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        pictures = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("pictures");
    }

    void MyFunction(GameObject picture, string name) {
        Texture2D tex = (Texture2D)Resources.Load(name, typeof(Texture2D));
        picture.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
        Debug.Log("change the texture " + name);
    }

    void Update() {
        foreach (GameObject picture in pictures) {
            if (Vector3.Distance(picture.transform.position, player.transform.position) < 20) {
                MyFunction(picture, picture.name);
            } else {
                Texture old = picture.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.GetTexture("_MainTex");
                Debug.Log(old.name);
                MyFunction(picture, old.name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code located? Start Function? Update Function?

Comment: i tried to put in update, and also in a my custom function but still doesn't work

Comment: pastebin the full code so I can take a look at it =)

Comment: ok, i edited the first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i solved it by myself, i created an array oldnames and in function Start i fill it with the old names of texture, then in Update if if the distance in bigger the function is called whit array index of oldnames that is the same of the texture obiouvsly because all the texture in array pictures have a name :)

PS: All texture must be in Resource folder!

Now it's time to check if it takes too much resources and if it is better to chose a triggers way...

I hope to help someone with this solution.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class pictures : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] pictures;   
    public GameObject player;

    List<string> oldnames = new List<string>();
    public Texture  old;
    public string oldName;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");    
        pictures = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag( "pictures" );

        foreach(GameObject picture in pictures)
        {
            old = picture.renderer.material.GetTexture ("_MainTex");
            oldName = old.name;
            oldnames.Add(oldName);
        }
    }

    void MyFunction(GameObject picture, string name) {

        Texture2D tex = (Texture2D) Resources.Load(name, typeof(Texture2D));
        picture.renderer.material.mainTexture = tex;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        for(int i = 0; i < pictures.Length; i++)
        { 
            GameObject picture = vetrine[i];            

            if (Vector3.Distance(picture.transform.position, player.transform.position) < 10)
            {
                MyFunction(picture, picture.name);
            } 
            else 
            { 
                MyFunction(picture, oldnames[i]);
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Note : `.renderer` is depreciated (Use `.GetComponent<Renderer>()` instead)

Answer (score 0):

`MyFunction2` never changes the texture, or the name. Where are you getting the other texture? I really don't understand.

How about this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Vetrine : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture2D textn;
    public GameObject[] pictures;
    public GameObject player;

    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        marker = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("infowindow");
        pictures = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("picture");
    }

    void MyFunction(GameObject picture, string name)
    {
        Texture2D tex = (Texture2D)Resources.Load(name, typeof(Texture2D));
        picture.renderer.material.mainTexture = tex;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        foreach (GameObject picture in pictures)
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(picture.transform.position, player.transform.position) < 20)
            {
                MyFunction(picture, picture.name);
            }
            else
            {
                MyFunction(picture, "someOtherNameHere");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that `pictures` is getting the result of `FindGameObjectsWithTag`, as it was empty before.

Comment: i tried to get the old texture from the inspector: 
public Texture2D oldTexture;
and in myfunction2:
picture.renderer.material.mainTexture = oldTexture;

Comment: i did'nt past myfunction2 content because i was working on it and i changed it

Comment: when you write MyFunction(picture, "someOtherNameHere"); i should take those picture from the model in run time (they are the old ones, understand?) but cause i can't do it i tryed to set those in pinspector without success...

Comment: ok, so just replace "someOtherNameHere" with the code that you use to take the name of the old ones...

Comment: maybe the problem is that, i used picture.renderer.material.GetTexture ("_MainTex"); but i doesn't work...

Comment: instead of trying to change the texture, for now, just use `Debug.Log` to print a message containing the texture name and your GameObject name. Put this just before the line that is changing the texture, that is  `picture.renderer.material.mainTexture = tex;`. I feel this part of the code is not being called.

Comment: where should i put picture.renderer.material.GetTexture ("_MainTex"); ?

if (Vector3.Distance(picture.transform.position, player.transform.position) < 20) {

      MyFunction(picture, picture.name);

}else{   
      Texture  old = picture.renderer.material.GetTexture ("_MainTex");
              Debug.Log(old.name);

     // MyFunction(picture, picture.name);

}           
Doing that seems to works to get the texture names

Comment: but wont work :(  using oldText =  picture.renderer.material.GetTexture ("_MainTex"); and then oldTextureName = oldText.name and calling the function by MyFunction(picture,oldTextureName); makes all my texture null :(